# change weight block drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I have 300 blocks in my site and when I wanted to change the weight of a block, JavaScript crashed and now I can't make changes to any blocks. How can I make a change to a block now?

Is there a way to change admin/builds/block to show any region in 1 page?

Comment: what do you mean when saying "JavaScript crashed"? This way it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the javascript you will be able to sort your blocks again.

Comment: OK i disable JavaScript but i have 500 block and my problem is loaded this page is 150 second and user want to use JavaScript for change weight

Comment: Are all your blocks generated by contrib modules?  Few users should access this page and should access a few times to this page. You can try to verify if there is not a slow query by enabling devel module and log query. You will see at the bottom of the page the slow queries in red and try to see if they are not generating some sort of problem.

Comment: There is no magic trick, either you try to reduce the number of blocks by merging some views with arguments, either you don't use that screen to reorder blocks weight, you could run a SQL query to update the weight of the blocks that you want.

Comment: may be this is one quick solution who know basic knowledge abot database, go to database, find your DB, select the blocks table, you will find the weight file,Now  do what ever you want,

Comment: OK but when one block change weight from DB this weight conflict with any block

Answer (score 0):

This worked for Drupal 7 and may work for Drupal 6: Try increasing the max_input_vars value in php.ini. Setting that value to 2000 worked in my case (Windows Server 2008/IIS/MySQL/PHP5.3 and over 200 Drupal blocks).

Troubleshooting tips for WIMP:
In php.ini, set: `error_log=C:\Windows\temp\php_errors.log`
In php_errors.log, look for a message such as: `"PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0"`